# event from onSelect returning null

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I have this weird problem (and I am sorry a newbie on this still) but I have a dropdown list that I want to be able to select from and pass back to a form to submit.  it works fine when I do the drop down line items manually, but when I retrieve it from the backend and then map, and try to handle the onSelect but the event on onSelect keeps returning null - so confused - do you see anything obvious in this code?

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useHttpClient } from '../hooks/http-hook';
import { validate } from '../util/validators';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownButton';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';

import './Input.css';

const Select = props => {
  console.log('props.id=' + props.id);
  console.log('props.label=' + props.label);
  const [selValue, setSelValue] = useState('');


  const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
  const [loadedFoodgroups, setLoadedFoodgroups] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchFoodgroups = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendRequest('http://localhost:5000/api/foodgroups')
        setLoadedFoodgroups(responseData);
        console.log('ResponseData' + JSON.stringify(responseData));

      } catch (err) { }
    };
    fetchFoodgroups();
  }, [sendRequest]);



  const handleSelect = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Select.js: handleSelect- event e=' + event.target.value);
    setSelValue(event.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <DropdownButton
        className="form-control__select"
        alignRight
        title="Foodgroups"
        id="dropdown-menu-align-right"
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        value={selValue}
      >
        <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
        {loadedFoodgroups.map(selectOptions => (
          <Dropdown.Item
            key={selectOptions.id}
            className="form-control__select"
            eventkey={selectOptions.id}>{selectOptions.name}
          </Dropdown.Item>
        ))}

      </DropdownButton>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Select;
```

Comment: More info. would be helpful. "but the event on onSelect keeps returning null " -- do you mean that `event.target.value` is null.  More importantly, can you post the output from `console.log('ResponseData' + JSON.stringify(responseData))`?

Comment: yes event.target.value is null - the console.log(...) is included here:
ResponseData[{"foods":["5f0baddcb194e0a15ecadb4d"],"_id":"5f0b8f43481b9a573f53ac4c","name":"fruits","__v":5},{"foods":[],"_id":"5f0bad545a16e69eccaf9e1a","name":"grains","__v":0},{"foods":["5f0c9939000b7e768103d1a3","5f0c9981000b7e768103d1a5"],"_id":"5f0c980a000b7e768103d1a1","name":"dairy","__v":2}]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the underlying issue is answered in some other questions (kind of), you have a few things you have to change, so here is a more specific answer for you:

First, the signature of `onSelect` is `(eventKey, event) => ...`, but in my testing the second param is not useful (target is null).  So even if you switch to using the second param in your handler, it probably won't work.  Instead, most people seem to be using the `eventKey` param like this:

```
const handleSelect = eventKey => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setSelValue(eventKey);
}
```

Which would probably meet your needs.

Before this will work for you, there are three typos to fix:

```
<Dropdown.Item
  key={selectOptions._id}. <--you have ".id" i your code but the data is "._id"
  className="form-control__select"
  eventKey={selectOptions.name}  <--you have "eventkey", with lowercase "k",             
                      // should be upper case.  
                      // You probably want the ".name" property here rather than
                      // "id", this is what will be passed into "onSelect"
>
```

So if you change your handler to use first param as `eventKey` and fix typos above, you should be able to set the state to the value selected from the dropdown button.

Comment: Thanks Henry - appreciate the help!  that worked like a charm!

Comment: I am glad that helped Ashish!  Do you mind accepting my answer since it helped you out?  Thanks!